# How do I make TFS aware that I no longer have the folder on my computer?

Tags: tfs

At one time, I had a version of a folder. Let's say it was c:\myfolder.
After that I deleted my local c:\myfolder. Now if I go to TFS it has the column last marked to 'yes' for the c:\myfolder.

How do I make TFS aware that I no longer have the c:\myfolder on my computer?

Comment: You're having problems with the quality filter because you're not capitalizing your I's and using proper punctuation, not because your question isn't long enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to get version 1. Right-click on the folder in TFS and select "Get Specific Version...". Change "Type" to "Changeset" and enter 1 for the changeset number. Since the files didn't exist for Changeset 1 TFS should now realize you no longer have the most recent.

Not sure I explained that well, but it's what works for me.

Edit: To give credit where credit is due - http://www.woodwardweb.com/tfs_top_tip/tfs_top_tip_11.html

Comment: It worked, TFS is no longer aware of my local folder. The odd thing is if i do a search on TFS it still thinks the local folder is in my computer.